# Image Source binding to file in local Storage

Tags: c#, wpf, image, xaml, windows-phone-8

In Windows Metro Apps (C#), I'm using a ValueConverter to pass an Image-Uri like this:

```
public class ProfileImage : IValueConverter {

    public Object Convert(Object value, Type targetType, Object parameter, String language) {

        if (value == null) {
            return "Common/images_profile/user.png";
        }

        return "ms-appdata:///local/" + (String)value;

    }

    public Object ConvertBack(Object value, Type targetType, Object parameter, String language) {
        return value;
    }

}
```

XAML:

```
<Image x:Name="profileImage" Height="80" Width="80" Source="{Binding Path, Converter={StaticResource ProfileImage}}"/>
```

The images are being downloaded async into localFolder.

I wanted to use this on Windows Phone 8 - but it doesn't show up any image.

```
var localFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
StorageFile myFile = await localFolder.CreateFileAsync(
    UID + ".jpg",
    CreationCollisionOption.FailIfExists);

using (var s = await myFile.OpenStreamForWriteAsync()) {
    s.Write(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
}
```

is used for writing the Images to the LocalStorage.

If there's no content in `value`, the Image in `Common/images_profile/user.png` is being displayed properly. This one is in the package, not in the local Folder.

I need to know which format I have to use as return parameter to get the images displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the URL scheme *ms-appdata:///* does not work everywhere.

I'm using this conveter for binding images from isolated storage:

```
public class PathToImageConverter : IValueConverter
{
    private static IsolatedStorageFile isoStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string path = value as string;

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(path))
            return null;

        if ((path.Length > 9) && (path.ToLower().Substring(0, 9).Equals("isostore:")))
        {
            using (var sourceFile = isoStorage.OpenFile(path.Substring(9), FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();
                image.SetSource(sourceFile);

                return image;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage(new Uri(path));

            return image;
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

For binding, you must use the *isostore:* prefix in your url.

Answer (score 0):

must be missing something here.. why don't you use StorageFile.Path instead of returning "return "ms-appdata:///local/" + (String)value;"

Realised that its #WP8 so another thing. You can still use isolated storage and Silverlight Uri